# How to add links to other portlets in Liferay dockbar -> user dropdown?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, portal

I've just got stuck with the portal when it comes to editing the dockbar. What I need to do is to have the possibility to customize (in principle add new portlets to) the dockbar's user dropdown (the one most right hand side).

What I mean is that when you open the dropdown list you have these fancy buttons such as my account, my dashboard, my profile. And I'd like to add there links to my own portlets like 'SamplePortlet' 'Hello' etc.
Specifically I want to give user the possibility to manage that, and let him put the portlets he wants there to appear, but at first I'd like to know how to modify it in general.

I think I've tried some stuff from the internet, hooks or properties but none seemed to do anything at all. Have you got any ideas?